Help with a non-homogeneous first-order ODE
I couldn't find an integrating factor for the equation
$$
(x^{2}-y)dx+x(y+1)dy=0
$$
I tried grouping it as
$$x^{2}dx+xydy=0$$
and
$$-ydx+xdy=0$$
which gave
$$ \frac{1}{x}g_{1}(x^{2}+y^{2})= \frac{1}{xy}g_{2}\left( \ln \left| \frac{y}{x} \right|  \right)$$
but I couldn't find functions
$g_1$and $g_2$that satisfy this relationship.
How should this equation be solved?

Maple classifies this differential equation as Abel class 2B.  I don't think there is an elementary way to do this.  Maple finds the implicit solution
$$ c +\arctan \! \left(\frac{y \! \left(x \right)}{\left(y \! \left(x \right)+1\right) \sqrt{\frac{-x^{2}-y \left(x \right)^{2}}{\left(y \left(x \right)+1\right)^{2}}}}\right)+\left(-y \! \left(x \right)-1\right) \sqrt{\frac{-x^{2}-y \! \left(x \right)^{2}}{\left(y \! \left(x \right)+1\right)^{2}}}
 = 0
$$
i.e. (with a different $c$)
$$ \text{arctanh}\left(\frac{y(x)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y(x)^2}}\right) + \sqrt{x^2 + y(x)^2} = c $$
